# ¿Como obtengo un determinado contador de todos los días de un rango de fecha, sino hay registro entre alguno de ellos que retorne un 0 en esa fecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Me explico mejor con un ejemplo sencillo que puede ser [ejecutado aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b563/3).

La consulta que realizo es para crear un contador de cada fecha en ese rango, y la idea es que, sino hay registros en alguno de esos días retorne 0 (para ese día que no tenga registros).

Imagen de lo que deseo:
[image: algo asi]

¿Se puede hacer con SQL o se tiene que hacer con JavaScript?

Comment: Pero... no son rangos, verdad? Son más bien fechas puntuales. ¿Podrías mostrar tu tabla de registros? Imagino que contiene una columna de fecha, una de turno y otra que sería el id único. ¿Qué más tiene esa tabla?

Comment: Viendo tu fiddle ¿Estás seguro que quieres contar los registros en vez de sumar sus valores?

Comment: @amenadiel buen punto, es la suma! se me paso por alto. ¿Pero entiendes mi pregunta?

Comment: Ahora murió el sqlfiddle así que no puedo probar.  Otra pregunta ¿Qiueres generar en esa tabla tantas columnas como filas tiene la tabla original?

Comment: @amenadiel estoy haciendo el fiddler de nuevo. Mmm quiero generar una tabla con todos los registros de que hay entre 2 fechas y que en donde no haya registros tambien traiga esa fecha con un 0.

Comment: Sí, pero la imagen que pusiste tiene la data transpuesta. Tu origen tiene N filas y quieres una respuesta de N columnas. A priori eso requeriría un procedimiento almacenado y el uso de la función crosstab.

Comment: Por si no funciona SQLFiddle, puedes probar http://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @amenadiel http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8ad02e17ce5653f049e866a1c5027de5

Comment: @amenadiel explico un poco, cada registro tiene un numero de lote, ese lote se le indica un producto a producir, se le indica un cantidad de operarios asignados a ese lote, la fecha y en que turno del dia se tiene planificado ese lote.

Comment: @amenadiel entonces la tabla que requiero de hacer debe tener todos los dias de un rango de fecha, es decir, el usuario indicara el dia inicial y el dia final en el que quiere ver los operarios asignados a cada fecha y especificando el turno en el que esta.

Comment: @amenadiel y como recalco, tambien trayendo las fechas que no tienen registros. Colocando un 0.

Comment: Hola Pablo. Lo ideal es de incluir todas las explicaciones directamente en tu pregunta, que en efecto las necesita.  Al final, no me quedó claro lo que buscabas, ni cómo la respuesta corresponde a la pregunta en su estado actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En postgres puedes generar un rango de fecha on the fly. En tu caso:

```
SELECT fecha::date dia
FROM generate_series ( '2017-03-01'::timestamp, '2017-03-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) fecha
```

Devuelve 31 filas, cada una con un día de marzo.

Haciendo un left join entre esa tabla y la tuya:

```
SELECT dias.dia, coalesce(sum(cant_operarios),0) operarios 
FROM (SELECT fecha::date dia
      FROM generate_series ( '2017-03-01'::timestamp, '2017-03-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) fecha ) dias
LEFT JOIN lotes on lotes.fecha = dias.dia
GROUP BY dias.dia
```

Obtienes una tabla con los 31 días y la cantidad de operarios, usando COALESCE para que los nulos pasen a ser ceros.

Y si quieres generar una columna por turno, sabiendo de antemano cuantos turnos hay:

```
select dias.dia, 
coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN turnos=1 THEN cant_operarios ELSE 0 END),0) turno1,
coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN turnos=2 THEN cant_operarios ELSE 0 END),0) turno2
FROM (SELECT fecha::date dia
      FROM generate_series ( '2017-03-01'::timestamp, '2017-03-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) fecha ) dias
LEFT JOIN lotes on lotes.fecha = dias.dia
group by dias.dia
```

[<kbd>Acá está el fiddle</kbd>](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cebe3ed2191f61857043f5af6a30e910)

Si no sabes cuantos turnos hay, el proceso para generar columnas dinámicamente es bastante más complicado.

Comment: esta respuesta me da a saber que no se nada de sql. Muchisimas gracias hermano.

Comment: no pude hacer el proceso para generar columnas dinámicamente, ¿sera que hago otra pregunta y te llegas allí o me podrías ayudar por acá?

Comment: de hecho, los turnos estan relacionados a otra tabla. Aca el ej de como lo manejo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30833/1 y http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=be60d8b62a5bfdcf0b2f25e09f3f7c65

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría hacer otra pregunta planteando específcamente el tema de cómo transponer la tabla. Incluso yo pensaría en solucionar eso en la capa de negocios y no tratar de hacer ese crosstab indeterminado en postgres

Comment: "capa de negocios" ???

Comment: php, java, node, c#, la capa de software desde donde pides la data a la BBDD

Comment: okok, ya entendi, gracias.