# ¿Como creo N cant de columnas en una consulta sql? en postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

En la consulta actual tengo estático a 2 columnas, pero yo quisiera que creara columnas por cada turno que hay en otra tabla.

Aca los 2 fiddle de lo que tengo:

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30833/1) y [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=be60d8b62a5bfdcf0b2f25e09f3f7c65)

**Actualización 1 (intentando especificar un poco mas):**

El `sql` que muestro en los ejemplos me genera una lista de fechas en donde consulta en la tabla "lotes" cuanta "cantidad de operarios" están asignados para cada fecha, el problema es que no encuentro, con `sql`, generar N cantidad de columnas para los turnos. Como ven hay "turno1" y "turno2" con la condicion de "id_turnos=1" y "id_turnos=2" pero no logro hacer que sean dinamicos, que me genere tantas columnas por tantos turnos que hayan. Como pueden ver hay una fecha registrada con el "id_turnos=3".

**NOTA:** ¿para que le dan a cerrar sino preguntan primero o solicitan mas especificación de la pregunta sino es entendida?.

**Actualización 2 (imagen adjunta):**

Tabla actual:

[image: tabla actual]

Tabla a la que se desea llegar:
[image: tabla objetiva]

**Actualización 3:**

Esta fue mi pregunta anterior y con la cual llegamos al sql que tengo actualmente.

[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55977/como-obtengo-un-determinado-contador-de-todos-los-d%C3%ADas-de-un-rango-de-fecha-si)

Comment: ¿Por que dar un voto para "cerrar" y no dejar siquiera un comentario?

Comment: Por favor, el que piense que deba cerrarse la pregunta es libre de darle a la opcion, pero por favor dejar un comentario explicando el ¿Por que?. Gracias!

Comment: La razón dado que veo en la revisión es "No esta claro que se pregunta". Eso normalmente debería haber generado un comentario por defecto, dirigiendote al centro de ayuda. A mi tampoco queda exactamente claro lo que intentas hacer, quizas un poco más ejemplo sería bueno.

Answer (score -2):

No queda claro el porque necesitas que estén en columnas, recuerda que SQL es un lenguaje que te permite obtener la información, digamos en "bruto", la forma de presentación de la información no es parte del él.  La información que necesitas la podés conseguir con el siguiente query

```
Select fecha,id_turnos, sum(cant_operarios) turnosAsignados from lotes group by fecha,id_turnos order by fecha,id_turnos
```

Comment: tengo que consultar todas las fechas de un rango de fecha, es decir, Ejemplo: de 2017-03-01 al 2017-03-31, a tu manera tendria q hacer un sql para cada uno.

Comment: para eso solo deberías colocar una clausula **where** adicional.